# WCF and Setspn.exe

Tags: wcf, kerberos

I have a self-hosted WCF that runs under network_service beautifully on \Server1, but needs to run under my credentials. When I start the service as myself, my ASP.NET application on \Server2 kicks out a "Call to SSPI Failed" error.

Tomasr recommended I download and use the Setspn utility (thanks!).

Now my big question is: Do I run Setspn on \Server1 (with the self-hosted WCF) or run Setspn on \Server2 (IIS hosted ASP application)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jason

Oh, forgot to mention: The WCF on \Server1 is using TCP. Not sure if that makes a difference, but most of the documentation I find seems to be geared for HTTP and IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had initially responded on your original question, but regarding the TCP part, [here](http://mastermynd-code.blogspot.com/2009/06/service-principal-name-when-using-wcf.html) is a good article explaining it in detail for net.tcp.